# Read DGN file in java or c#

Tags: gdal, c#, java, dgn

I'm looking solution to read DGN file in java or c# without any success.
Gdal makes many problem and doesn't support all element eg. complex element.

Does anyone know of a library that supports the reading of all the elements DGN file?

Where I can find format dgn file?

Comment: By following the links from GDAL DGN driver page to http://dgnlib.maptools.org/ and again to http://www.bentley.com/en-US/Products/MicroStation/OpenDGN/ you can find more info.

Comment: Which particular DGN version are you trying to read?

Answer (score 0):

DGNLib is a small C/C++ library.

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE .. it is appropriate if you add a link to the Library and the reference material in your answers to help future users who may see your response. One line responses are not recommended as they do not give enough information. Can you please expand your answer?

Comment: This appears to be a comment rather than an answer to the question.  Is the point that you wanted to raise that DGNLib is a C++ library only, so not helpful for a question on Java/C#?

Answer (score 0):

@vink is correct.
DGN is short form for 'design'.The file is used for storing CAD drawings.
Most popular versions of DGN are v7 by Intergraph and v8 an improved version by Microstation.The internal format is described in [dgnlib](http://dgnlib.maptools.org/) c/c++ library [website](http://dgnlib.maptools.org/dgn.html).You may want to write your own parser looking at the format internals.If you want specifically in C# there is an SDK called [RealDWG](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=770257) from Autodesk corporation.

Comment: DGNlib only does v7, and DGNlib is what GDAL uses. So I'm not sure how this will help.